# SQL error reading a value from a text file to use in WHERE clause and YYYY-DD-MM localized DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

There is a file `C: /date.txt`, there is only one date stored here, for example `02-08-2018`.

How do I in SQL select the data that is greater than this date?

if I so will write a request

```
SELECT Dt, col,col2, col3...
FROM  mytab1 WHERE Dt> C: /date.txt
```

How do I make the condition  > C: /date.txt, and not > 02-08-2018?

**Edit**:

```
DECLARE @FileContents VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @FileContents = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\sql\rscript\SQL_MaxDate.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

SELECT t.*
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         CustomerName, [ItemRelation], [DocumentNum], [DocumentYear], CustomerType 
     FROM  
         [Action].dbo.mytab1
     WHERE 
         Dt > @FileContents AND [IsPromo] = 1 
     GROUP BY
         CustomerName, [ItemRelation],
         [DocumentNum], [DocumentYear], CustomerType 
     HAVING
         COUNT(*) >= 5) AS x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Action].dbo.mytab1 AS t ON x.ItemRelation = t.[ItemRelation] 
                             AND x.[DocumentNum] = t.[DocumentNum] 
                             AND x.[DocumentYear] = t.[DocumentYear]
                             AND x.[CustomerName] = t.[CustomerName]
                             AND x.[CustomerType] = t.[CustomerType]
```

error

> Converting a varchar data type to a datetime data type has resulted in a value out of range.

**Edit 2**:

```
2017-12-05 00:00:00.000
2017-12-03 00:00:00.000
2017-12-04 00:00:00.000
2017-11-18 00:00:00.000
2017-12-02 00:00:00.000
2017-11-27 00:00:00.000
2017-11-28 00:00:00.000
2017-11-17 00:00:00.000
2017-12-01 00:00:00.000
2017-11-26 00:00:00.000
```

[image]

Comment: `WHERE Dt> C: /date.txt` is not valid SQL Server syntax. To clarify, please post what you are actually using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `Dt> C: /date.txt` isn't valid SQL.  So you need to open the file and pull it the value into SQL.  As per our extensive chat, the date format also needs to be changed due to localized `DATETIME` to a `YYYY-DD-MM` format.

```
DECLARE @FileContents  VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @FileContents=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\date.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

DECLARE @NEWDATE VARCHAR(100)
SET @NEWDATE = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @FileContents)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, @FileContents)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, @FileContents)))

SELECT * FROM [Action].dbo.mytab1 WHERE Dt > @NEWDATE
```

The file `date.txt` simply contains one line that contains:

```
02-08-2018
```

Like this:

[image]

Comment: i edited post, please check edit, i work with complex query. I get error Converting a varchar data type to a datetime data type has resulted in a value out of range. please check

Comment: If you hard code `02-08-2018` as the `@FileContents` do you get the same error?  I want to figure out of it's the dateformat in the file, or if SQL is expecting something else?

Comment: indeed date in this  format 2018-06-27,  but yes i get same error.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer, perhaps it need to be specifically converted to `DATETIME`

Comment: hm, strange, it is same error Converting a varchar data type to a datetime data type has resulted in a value out of range.

Comment: That is strange..  what if you simply try `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Action].dbo.mytab1 WHERE Dt > '2018-06-27'` Something seems off with this error like `Dt` isn't a `DATETIME`.  If that works, then perhaps just work backwards adding the value from the file and other conditions until it blows up.

Comment: you are right SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Action].dbo.mytab1 WHERE Dt > '2018-06-27'  returns this error ,  but dt has type datetime not null.

Comment: Something.. isn't right then.  If you select something out of that column, what does it look like?  If it's a strange dateformat you'll probably have to `CONVERT` to mimic it.  Perhaps it's `mm-dd-yyyy` ?

Comment: I edited post, where show how looks dt column. please check

Comment: Hm!  Try: `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Action].dbo.mytab1 WHERE Dt > '2017-11-26 00:00:00.000'`  and see if that doesn't blow up.

Comment: I wonder if the datatype is actually a datetime.  Try `sp_help 'mytab1'`  perhaps `Dt` is a varchar or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177286/discussion-between-d-joe-and-sniperd).

Answer (score 1):

Create a table and insert the date value into the table as given below. This code should work. I did not test it myself. You can get idea on how to execute it.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tempDate(DateValue DATE);

BULK INSERT dbo.tempDate
   FROM 'c:\date.txt'
   WITH 
      (
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
      );

SELECT Dt, col,col2, col3...
FROM  mytab1 
WHERE Dt > (SELECT MAX(DateValue) FROM dbo.tempDate);
```